# Let a BIND DNS server query to a second one

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I connected two private networks using a VPN tunnel. The communication between the two networks is working good.

Well, the networks `A` and `B` have their own [BIND DNS servers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) for the domains `network-a.mycompany.com` and `network-b.mycompany.com`, respectively.

Now, **I need the DNS server on network A be able to query to DNS server on network B, and vice versa**. The idea is let the users on network `A`, for example, ask to their own DNS and be able to resolve names from both domains without change the DNS configuration on their computers.

I was reading the BIND manual, but because this is new for me, I don't know what kind of configuration I'm looking for.

How can I do that?

Comment: In Windows DNS this is called a Conditional Forwarder. Look for something similarly named in BIND.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @joeqwerty. It was necessary to edit `named.conf` on the DNS server in network A.

```
zone "network-b.mycompany.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.17.0.1; };  // The DNS server's address in network B
};
```

Source: [Conditional DNS forwarding with named on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/99101/conditional-dns-forwarding-with-named-on-linux)