# Connecting two internal DNS domains

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I have 2 networks with 2 private DNS suffixes, let's say one is "*.a1.lan" and the second one is "*.pink.zone". In first network there is Windows DNS server with zone files for "a1.lan" in the second network there is Linux BIND server with zone files for "pink.zone". I need to resolve addresses from a1.lan in pink.zone. Both servers can see themselves. 
Is there any way to create some kind of record in pink.zone which will create referral to a1.lan?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a conditional forwarder on BIND (and on Windows AD):

```
zone "a1.lan" {
   type forward;
   forward only;
   forwarders { 10.0.0.1; };
};
```

where 10.0.0.1 is the IP address of your Windows AD domain controller with integrated DNS server.

See also:

- [Conditional DNS forwarding with named on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/99101/conditional-dns-forwarding-with-named-on-linux)